# How to end assembly correctly?

Tags: assembly, dos

I have a problem correctly terminating a 16bit DOS program written in Assembly.  Here's part of code:

```
.386P
.model flat

stack_s segment stack 'stack' 
        db 256 dup(0)
stack_s ends

data segment use16
data ends

code segment 'code' use16
assume cs:code, ds:data

main proc
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax

    iretd
main endp

code ends
end main
```

The problem is, that the program doesn't terminate in a correct way.  DOSBox just freezes.  I tried to understand what happens using debugger, and it seems the program just ends up in an infinite loop after `iretd` is performed.  Why does this happen?  How can do I terminate a 16bit DOS app correctly?

Comment: Try changing `iretd` to `ret`

Comment: I've tried to do this already. It doesn't work.

Comment: What about `mov ax, 4c00h` followed by `int 21h` (this is a recommended way to terminate DOS application)

Comment: Terminating a DOS program requires a system call.  Int 21h with ah = 4Ch and al = exit code.

Comment: Well, i tried to write mov ah, 4ch and int 21h, but nothing changed.

Comment: Sorry, I've just tried to trace the code. Debugger says that program is terminated. The problem is that when I try to run program itself: dosbox freezes as it was before. Maybe problem is caused by dosbox?

Comment: @Farrel: did you manage to figure this out?  I'm having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most correct way to end a DOS program is to use the "terminate" DOS function; followed by adequate comments so that people understand that this function won't return.

For example:

```
pleaseKillMeNow:
    mov ah,0x4C          ;DOS "terminate" function
    int 0x21
```

Answer (score 7):

Brendan's answer shows how to exit but it leaves the error level undefined (it will be whatever is in the AL register...)

If you want to exit with error level 0:

```
mov ax,0x4c00
int 0x21
```

If you want to exit with error level 1:

```
mov ax,0x4c01
int 0x21
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit without any particular error code this is the way to go:

```
mov ax,4C00h
int 21h
```

But if you want to return a particular error code, this is a better way:

```
; ...
ErrorCode db 0   ; set a default error code
; ...
mov ErrorCode,1h ; change the error code if needed
; ...
mov ah,4Ch       ; prepare to exit
mov al,ErrorCode ; and return the error code
int 21h
```

Comment: `mov ax,4C00h` sets AH=4Ch and AL=0, so `int 21h` will exit with status 0.  If you don't care about the exit status, just set AH=4Ch and leave garbage in AL.  Or use `int 20h` without setting any registers first if CS is still set to the initial value ([What is the difference between \`MOV AX,4C00H INT 21H\` and \`INT 20H\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72918078)).  There's no need for having a named variable in static storage; usually if you're about to exit, you know why and whether it's success or failure.

Comment: @PeterCordes Not caring for the exit code of your program does not mean that the people using your program don't care about the exit code. To me, not caring for the exit code means outputing the same exit code whatever happens during the execution of the program.

Comment: @PeterCordes for your second remark, I must admit I lack experience in assembly coding. It seemed to me a good idea to have one place where my exit code lies so I can do some clean up before exiting, if necessary (like closing open connections or files for example). In tat case, it becomes necessary to be able to set the error code where the problem appeared and run your exit code somewhere else.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for pointing to the post on the difference between `MOV AX,4C00H INT 21H` and `INT 20H`, very instructive.