# What is the difference between `MOV AX,4C00H INT 21H` and `INT 20H`?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, exit, dosbox

I know that both of those terminate the program, but why use `MOV AX,4C00H INT 21H` when I could just do `INT 20H`?

Comment: `INT 20h` doesn't let you control the program exit code.

Comment: @RaymondChen I suppose that's the only difference?

Comment: The major other difference is that `int 20h` terminates the process at whose CS we are right now whereas `int 21h/AX=4C00h` terminates the active process (which I think is the topmost process on the process stack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `int 20h` DOS.TerminateProgram interrupt and its operationally identical sibling `mov ah, 00h` `int 21h` DOS.TerminateProgram function were present in DOS version 1. They both rely on the `CS` segment register pointing at the segment that contains the ProgramSegmentPrefix aka PSP.
- The `mov ax, 4C??h` `int 21h` DOS.TerminateWithReturnCode function was introduced with DOS version 2. This new function allows returning an exit code to the parent process, and does not rely on having `CS` point at the PSP.

Function 4Ch is the preferred way to terminate a program in DOS versions 2 and better. However, if you don't care about returning an exit code, you can just use the `int 20h` interrupt and shave off a few byte. You don't have to worry about having `CS` point at the PSP either since DOS versions 2+ will silently make your `int 20h` act as if it was a `mov ax, 4C00h` `int 21h` sequence with an exit code of 0.

Ultimately though you have to find out for yourself if the above is true. All sorts of emulators/environments could implement it in their own ways. I believe DEBUG.EXE differentiates between the two...